# Is resolution of an image lost when uploading a JPG image into Android Studio as a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I am working on an Android application that looks at different properties of images and I noticed that if I start with a JPG image with dimensions 1920x1080 and upload that image into my app as a bitmap by opening the gallery and selecting the appropriate image, the bitmap dimensions are 1024x576.  I did not declare a width or height for the bitmap and although I do eventually set my bitmap as an imageView, when I put a break point in my code before this happens the dimensions are still low.

Do I lose resolution in my image?

How can I import images as bitmaps without sacrificing resolution?

Below is my code for importing my image from external storage on the phone into my app

```
public void openGallery(View v){

     runStop = false;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStartScan);
    mStreamButton.setText("Start stream");

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100);

    ppm = 0;
    numberOfDots = 0;

    if (countParticles.equals(true)){
        mDots.setText(null);
        mPpm.setText(null);
    }



    uploadedImage = true;

    //listItems.clear();
   // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try{
            imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        if (processImage.equals(true)){
            convertToGray();
        }
    }
}
```

[Crude comparison of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9vdF.jpg)

Below is a zoomed in comparison of two of the same points.  The Android Studio debugger allows bitmaps to be viewed, but not copied or saved so the best I could do is print screen while both images are open on my screen.

Comment: Using JPEG also impacts image quality.

Comment: You could create a simple routine that converts your 1920x1080 JPG into  a 1920x1080 BMP on the client side. You could then send the BMP file to the server side. This might be a possible walkaround for not sacrificing resolution in the data-transfer stage.

Comment: @Employee I think my problem is more simple than you think.  I do exchange data via wifi but for this specific problem I am looking at images downloaded onto my phone.  They are from the same source and automatically get saved as 1920x1080 JPG files.  I just can't figure out why my dimensions are changed when uploading the image

Comment: How exactly did you determine that `imageBitmap` is 1024x576?

Comment: @greeble31 you can see the size when debugging.  I first noticed when I was looking at cropping one of the images.

Comment: Yes, but what fields are you looking at, in particular?

Comment: I was looking at the original image for small particles (that only take up about 4 pixels) and trying to find the contours based off of the particle color in gray scale compared to the background.  In the original image the gray scale gap is really large but in the smaller bitmap with a lower resolution, the image colors are averaged out so the gap is not as big

Comment: @KyleG I meant, "what fields are you looking at (in the debugger) to determine that `imageBitmap` is 1024x576"? I'm still not at all clear how you're doing this. Your last comment nevertheless raises additional questions - would it be possible for you to add before/after images to your question?

Comment: @greeble31 sorry, I misunderstood.  When debugging you can view the bitmap and the dimensions are given, 1024x576, 32bit color.  I can't exactly get a perfect side by side comparison because when viewing a bitmap while debugging, the image closes when anything else is clicked and it cannot be coped and saved.  I added a print screen comparison though, I'm not sure if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: No resolution is lost.

I think you were misled by a very confusing display on the Android Studio "View Bitmap" window. It's not displaying the actual size of the bitmap in pixels. I'm not sure exactly what that is (anybody?); maybe it's `dp`.

It's also clear that the "View Bitmap" image is being downsampled. That's why the pixels look different to you. The preview window is definitely *not* presenting the image in the same fidelity as it exists in the memory of your `Bitmap` object.

A better way to check `Bitmap's` actual dimensions is to look at the `mWidth` and `mHeight` members, or use `Bitmap.getWidth()/getHeight()`.

In case you don't believe me, notice that there is a clue in the image you posted, at the very bottom. It's very hard to see, but you can tell that `imageBitmap's` `mBuffer` is 8294400 bytes long.

```
1920 x 1080 x 4 (bytes per pixel) = 8294400
```

(I tested this on my own box, I was able to reproduce the issue. Trust me -- the actual `Bitmap` is full size, with no data loss.)

Comment: You're right.  I checked the bitmap width and height using getWidth and getHeight and they match the jpg dimensions.  Thank you